# Cassandra PHP Client for CQL 3.0

Tags: php, client, cassandra, cql

I recently upgraded my cassandra cluster to 1.2 and i have searched for a php client that supports Cassandra 1.2, with full CQL 3.0 and using the new protocol (not thrift).

Neither phpcassa, simplecassie, cassandra-pdo, etc, etc, today seems to support full CQL 3.0 (composite types and collections, for example, returns errors on the data). I also don't found any public effort going to make a php client with full support.

Anyone knoes any php client that comes closer to a full support, or its going toward it? Or, if not in php, maybe in python?

Comment: It´s a good pratice explain why the question was closed as "not constructive". My question it´s direct and objective, and not solicit debate, polling, etc, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure why it was closed; it's a valid question.  Since I cannot post an answer, I'll answer here.  There is not a CQL 3 PHP client that uses the native binary protocol yet.  I would expect work to be started on one within the next couple of months in a form similar to https://github.com/datastax/java-driver.

Comment: Thanks Tyler, i will continue searching new CQL 3 initiatives and post here the news.

Comment: In fact, I found this question useful.

Comment: Try YACassandraPDO from [https://github.com/Orange-OpenSource/YACassandraPDO]

Comment: In the end, i'm created a Tomcat PhpJavaDriver (PHP + PhpJavaBridge + Cassandra java Driver), a webservice that PHP calls. With this webservice, we can use full CQL3 implementation, use connection poll, cache of resources, etc. It works very well! (look at pollkan.com). If anyone want to have a look, say me and i can upload it to github.